# C language 2d Array Fun Game Crossword

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, codeblocks

I am given a crossword crossword[20][20] its already fulled with words so i dont need to generate. I need to scan for words **horizontally ONLY** and put them in a new array. One word per line so the new array will be array[40][20].
**NOTE: The crossword has maximum 40 horizontal words!** So i only need 40 lines in the array. If the words<40 then the other cells in the array will remain '\0'.
The black boxes are the '*'.
The given crossword is this:

```
char crossword[20][20]={
                {'*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'},
                {'*','T','Y','P','E','*','*','*','*','G','U','I','T','A','R','I','S','T','*','*'},
                {'*','E','*','*','V','A','I','N','*','A','*','*','*','V','*','*','T','*','I','*'},
                {'*','R','O','M','E','*','*','*','*','M','A','R','R','I','A','G','E','*','N','*'},
                {'*','R','*','*','N','O','O','D','L','E','*','O','*','A','*','*','A','N','T','*'},
                {'*','I','N','*','*','*','*','O','*','*','*','P','E','T','R','O','L','*','I','*'},
                {'*','F','*','C','*','C','U','T','*','L','I','E','*','I','*','A','T','O','M','*'},
                {'*','I','*','O','*','U','*','*','M','*','N','*','M','O','U','T','H','*','A','*'},
                {'*','E','N','V','E','L','O','P','E','*','F','*','I','N','*','H','*','A','T','*'},
                {'*','D','*','E','*','T','*','*','A','*','E','*','N','*','*','*','A','G','E','*'},
                {'*','*','A','R','T','*','I','N','T','E','R','I','O','R','*','A','*','O','*','*'},
                {'*','K','*','*','O','*','R','*','*','A','T','*','R','O','B','B','E','R','Y','*'},
                {'*','A','T','*','A','I','R','*','S','T','I','R','*','O','*','O','*','A','*','*'},
                {'*','N','O','*','S','*','I','T','*','*','L','*','S','M','I','L','E','*','S','*'},
                {'*','G','*','*','T','*','T','*','O','*','I','*','O','*','N','I','G','H','T','*'},
                {'*','A','C','E','*','M','A','N','D','A','T','O','R','Y','*','T','O','*','O','*'},
                {'*','R','*','N','Y','*','T','*','E','*','Y','*','T','*','*','I','*','*','P','*'},
                {'*','O','*','D','O','*','E','*','*','*','*','I','*','O','Z','O','N','E','*','*'},
                {'*','O','N','*','U','N','D','E','R','W','A','T','E','R','*','N','O','U','N','*'},
                {'*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'}
};
```

So what i have done so far is this, but it is not correct because i do it with nerdy way...:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char cross[20][20]={
                {'*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'},
                {'*','T','Y','P','E','*','*','*','*','G','U','I','T','A','R','I','S','T','*','*'},
                {'*','E','*','*','V','A','I','N','*','A','*','*','*','V','*','*','T','*','I','*'},
                {'*','R','O','M','E','*','*','*','*','M','A','R','R','I','A','G','E','*','N','*'},
                {'*','R','*','*','N','O','O','D','L','E','*','O','*','A','*','*','A','N','T','*'},
                {'*','I','N','*','*','*','*','O','*','*','*','P','E','T','R','O','L','*','I','*'},
                {'*','F','*','C','*','C','U','T','*','L','I','E','*','I','*','A','T','O','M','*'},
                {'*','I','*','O','*','U','*','*','M','*','N','*','M','O','U','T','H','*','A','*'},
                {'*','E','N','V','E','L','O','P','E','*','F','*','I','N','*','H','*','A','T','*'},
                {'*','D','*','E','*','T','*','*','A','*','E','*','N','*','*','*','A','G','E','*'},
                {'*','*','A','R','T','*','I','N','T','E','R','I','O','R','*','A','*','O','*','*'},
                {'*','K','*','*','O','*','R','*','*','A','T','*','R','O','B','B','E','R','Y','*'},
                {'*','A','T','*','A','I','R','*','S','T','I','R','*','O','*','O','*','A','*','*'},
                {'*','N','O','*','S','*','I','T','*','*','L','*','S','M','I','L','E','*','S','*'},
                {'*','G','*','*','T','*','T','*','O','*','I','*','O','*','N','I','G','H','T','*'},
                {'*','A','C','E','*','M','A','N','D','A','T','O','R','Y','*','T','O','*','O','*'},
                {'*','R','*','N','Y','*','T','*','E','*','Y','*','T','*','*','I','*','*','P','*'},
                {'*','O','*','D','O','*','E','*','*','*','*','I','*','O','Z','O','N','E','*','*'},
                {'*','O','N','*','U','N','D','E','R','W','A','T','E','R','*','N','O','U','N','*'},
                {'*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'}
};

int main(){
    int i, j, start_index, end_index, a, b, start_index1, end_index1;
    char cross1[40][20], cross11[40][20];
    for(i=0;i<40;i++){
        for(j=0;j<20;j++){
            cross1[i][j]='\0';
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<40;i++){
        for(j=0;j<20;j++){
            cross11[i][j]='\0';
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<19;i++){
        start_index = -1;
        end_index=-1;
        start_index1 = -1;
        end_index1=-1;
        for(j=0;j<20;j++){
            if(isalpha(cross[i][j]) && (!isalpha(cross[i][j-1])) && isalpha(cross[i][j+1]) && start_index==-1){
                start_index = j;
            }
            if(isalpha(cross[i][j]) && (!isalpha(cross[i][j+1])) && isalpha(cross[i][j-1]) && end_index==-1){
                end_index = j;
            }
            if(isalpha(cross[i][j]) && (!isalpha(cross[i][j-1])) && isalpha(cross[i][j+1])){
                start_index1 = j;
            }
            if(isalpha(cross[i][j]) && (!isalpha(cross[i][j+1])) && isalpha(cross[i][j-1])){
                end_index1 = j;
            }
        }
        for(a=start_index,b=0;a<=end_index;a++,b++){
            cross1[i][b]=cross[i][a];
        }
        for(a=start_index1,b=0;a<=end_index1;a++,b++){
            cross11[i][b]=cross[i][a];
        }
    }
    printf("CROSS1\n");
    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        for(j=0;j<20;j++){
            printf("%c ", cross1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("CROSS11\n");
    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        for(j=0;j<20;j++){
            printf("%c ", cross11[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is this:

```
CROSS1

TYPE
VAIN
ROME
NOODLE
IN
CUT
MOUTH
ENVELOPE
AGE
ART
AT
AT
NO
NIGHT
ACE
NY
DO
ON

CROSS11

GUITARIST
VAIN
MARRIAGE
ANT
PETROL
ATOM
MOUTH
AT
AGE
INTERIOR
ROBBERY
STIR
SMILE
NIGHT
TO
NY
OZONE
NOUN
```

The problem is that i want it in one arrray not in two (cross1, cross11) and also some words are printed twice (both in cross1 and cross11 like the "MOUTH"), also another problem is that some words dont even printed like the: "LIE"
Any help appreciated and rewarded!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your code only works if you have at most two words per line. Look at your original array: on `cross[6]` you have CUT, LIE and ATOM. You put CUT in `cross1`, then put LIE in `cross11`, you come across ATOM and you overwrite LIE in `cross11`, so LIE never gets stored.

A good solution would be to get rid of `start_index`, `end_index` and `cross11`, since `start_index1` and `end_index1` do what they're supposed to. You will also need to have a variable `row` of type `int` to keep track of where you are within `cross1`, in order to make sure you don't overwrite stuff anymore. And as soon as you set a different value for `end_index1`, stick it in `cross1`, something like this:

```
if(isalpha(cross[i][j]) && (!isalpha(cross[i][j+1])) && isalpha(cross[i][j-1])){
    end_index1 = j;
    //now do this right here, not outside the j-loop
    for(a=start_index1,b=0;a<=end_index1;a++,b++){ 
        cross1[row][b]=cross[i][a];
    }
    row++; //variable which will keep track of the row you're in for cross1
}
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out.